# Counting word frequency in original file and mapping them

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, counter, countvectorizer

I'm trying to use a modified version of count vectorizer where I use it to fit on a series.
Then I get the sum of all the counts for values in cells.
E.g: This is my series on which I'm fitting the count vectorizer.

```
["dog cat mouse", " cat mouse", "mouse mouse cat"]
```

The end result should look something like:

```
[1+3+4, 3+4, 4+4+3]
```

I've tried using `Counter` but it doesn't really work in this case.
So far I've only been successful in getting a sparse matrix but that prints out the total number of elements in the cell. However I want to map the count to the entire series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items of the counter list can only be stored in the form of string, later a string can be evaluated using `eval()`

Code:

```
lst = ["dog cat mouse", " cat mouse", "mouse mouse cat"]
res = {}
res2 = []
for i in lst:
    for j in i.split(' '):
        if j not in res.keys():
            res[j] = 1
        else:
            res[j] += 1

for i in lst:
    res2.append('+'.join([str(res[j]) for j in i.split(' ')]))

print(res2)
```

The result (`res2`) should be like `['1+3+4', '3+4', '4+4+3']`

I think this is what you want...

Comment: I guess that OP want the occurence of each word not the length of each word.

Comment: I edited the code, now check whether it's working for you

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a modified version of this code. Instead of defining a new dictionary, I ended up using `cv.vocabulary_`. The rest of the code was same as yours.